# Proving that if $A \approx (A-\{x\})$, then $A$ is an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving the following statement

$A \approx (A-\{x\})$, if and only if $A$ is an infinite set

I have proven the reverse direction, but am having trouble with proving the forward direction: Proving that if $A \approx (A-\{x\})$, then $A$ is an infinite set

My thinking is that since there is a theorem that says:

A is infinite if and only if it is equipotent with a proper subset of itself,
We are assuming that $A \approx (A-\{x\})$, so doesn't that mean that A is infinite and we are done?

Comment: You need to require that $A$ is non-empty, otherwise $\varnothing$ satisfies this as well.

Comment: Let $x\in A$. $A$ infinite iff equipotent to proper subset $A\setminus \{x\}$ solves your problem

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I'd say we need to require $x\in A$, since if $x \not\in A$, it would be true of any set!

Comment: @hardmath: Well, that depends how you quantify $x$. I used a universal quantifier.

Comment: Oops yes the question says to assume that $x \in A$ does that mean i am done?

Comment: Prove that if $A$ is a finite set and $x \in A$, then $A$ is not equipotent to $A\setminus \{x\}$.